# how to get user's posts & updates from Google plus like facebook

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, google-plus

I want to get all wall updates of user's google plus account like facebook.
I have seen official link for it which is

[Google Plus Documentation for iOS](http://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started)

& I have downloaded sample from there which is here [Google Plus SDK Sample](http://goo.gl/oQgMX)

it works well for getting user's information like email id,profile name,user's friend list with images & for posting on google plus.

but I am not getting user's post & updates.

all I want is user's wall updates & user's friends updates from google plus like facebook does.

but from above link i have found nothing for getting wall updates.

I have searched google for this also & get nothing regarding above problem.

any help for above problem appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From a backend server you can easily perform this API call to read a user's public activities. You can see the REST API here:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.list

Combine this with a [people.list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.list) and you can query for a user's friend activities on Google+.

On iOS, you probably don't want to make these API calls directly from a user's device. If you can, you should offload the work to a backend server to avoid overworking the mobile client. That said, you can perform an API query similar to listing people in circles:

```
GTLQueryPlus *query =
  [GTLQueryPlus queryForActivitiesListWithUserId:@"me" collection:@"public"];

[[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] plusService] executeQuery:query
                                     completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                         GTLPlusActivityFeed *actFeed,
                                                         NSError *error) {
}
```

If you put a breakpoint in the application on the function, the activities feed will be something like as follows:

```
(lldb) po actFeed
{
  nextPageToken:"CAIQ44qZ58DgtwIgFCgB"
  etag:""DOKFJGXi7L9ogpHc3dzouWOBEEg/UMVQXfw8ynZaTz31tpuZo473TsQ"" 
  title:"Google+ List of Activities for Collection PUBLIC" 
  updated:"2013-07-16T04:04:34.697Z" 
  kind:"plus#activityFeed" items:[20]
}
```

The items array contains the actual activities that a user has publicly written on Google+.

Comment: thanks for the nice explanation i have tried REST API but it requires oauth atuthentication and on google's developer site have not  provide any information how to get  access token from iphone or android device for ios they have given SDK. i will try your solution & let you know

Comment: can you please give any code sample how to Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0 in iphone for rest api.

Comment: The iOS quick-start app demonstrates many features of the Google+ API, including how to do authorization between the iOS client and your server. https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/ios

Comment: @Joanna i have mentioned that link in my above question which is regarding ios sdk of google+ i want to try http api given in this link https://developers.google.com/+/api/ but i have no idea how to Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0 so that i can get users info